# Regex help need

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to replace `model => model.Password`  substring within `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)`.

Any clue which regex template I have use to?

I have tried `\\(.+?\\)`   Is this correct?

Thank you!

```
var match = Regex.Match(view, @"@Html.DisplayNameFor(\\(.+?\\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern should be more like:

```
@"@Html\.DisplayNameFor\((.+?)\)"
```

Since you were already using a verbatim string (`@""`), you shouldn't have included the double backslashes.  Also, the `.` should have been escaped, and I adjusted the grouping parens to match `model => model.Password` instead of `(model => model.Password)`.

And if you're trying to replace, you may want to just use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) directly instead of first `Match`ing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this statement:

```
var match = Regex.Match(view, @"@Html.DisplayNameFor(\\(.+?\\))", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You used `@` before the regex pattern to escape all characters. In this case, it's not necessary escape your pattern again using one more `"\"`. So, this code should be more like:

```
var match = Regex.Match(view, @"@Html.DisplayNameFor(\(.+?\))",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Or you can remove the `@` to continue using double slashes:

```
var match = Regex.Match(view, "@Html.DisplayNameFor(\\(.+?\\))",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```